# vsftpd can't login after adding a new user

Tags: vsftpd

I'm running a Ubuntu Server 16.04
and had a vsftpd Server that i setup about two months ago with a tutorial (linked [HERE](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-18-04)). today i needed to add another user with sFTP access and did it in the same way. but now no user is working.

when i want to login i get:

```
myuser@myuser-Pc:~$ sftp sftpuser@mydomain
sftpuser@mydomain's password: 
Connection to mydomain closed by remote host.
Connection closed
```

my /etc/vsftpd.conf file: https://pastebin.com/rM5rFvyk

my /etc/vsftp.userlist file:

```
mysftpuser
mysftpuser2
```

(All users are existing)

It also doesn't run when I remove the new user from the userlist
The /etc/vsftp.userlist looks like that then:
    mysftpuser

I really need the FTP access, i hope someone here can help me.

## Update

I fixed the problem. I tried if FTPs (not sFTP) is working on the users and yes it does work. But before I added the second user, sFTP also worked. Why does it not work now? (new question)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all users are actually system users ( added via `useradd` or while system installation ).

Comment: I've added all the users like in the tutorial I linked, so that's not the problem. thank you for the answer